# Date format of milliseconds shows SSS only

Tags: android, kotlin, time

I'm trying to get the current time including milliseconds, but it only shows SSS.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
...

String.format(
    "%s IOException: %s",
    DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Calendar.getInstance().time),
    ex.message
)
```

It outputs `20:41:03.SSS some other text`. Also tried just toasting the date, same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can't get milliseconds with `DateFormat`, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat`, so your code should look like this:

```
String.format(
    "%s IOException: %s",
    SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().time),
    ex.message
)
```

and also you could use `Date()` instead of `Calendar.getInstance().time`

```
String.format(
    "%s IOException: %s",
    SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date()),
    ex.message
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, it should work

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
...

String.format(
    "%s IOException: %s",
    new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().time),
    ex.message
)
```